# Not able to add chat message using Sockjs in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, chatbot, stompjs

I am facing issue in adding chat message in my Flatlist because I am not able to call any function inside **stompClient.subscribe ()**
My code is as following :

```
     dummy='dummyurl';
sock = new SockJS(this.dummy);

componentDidMount() {
var that = this;
this.sock.onConnect =(e) =>{
 console.log("connected")
}
this.sock.onopen = function() {
 console.log('open');
 var dummy2='dummyurl';
  var sock2 = new SockJS(dummy2);
   let stompClient = Stomp.over(sock2);
        stompClient.heartbeat.outgoing = 20000;
        stompClient.heartbeat.incoming = 0;
        stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
      stompClient.subscribe('xyz/getChat', (messageOutput) =>{
         var mymessage =JSON.parse(messageOutput.body).message;
         this.state = {
           incomingchatMessage: "",
           chatMessages:[]
         }
         that.setState({incomingchatMessage:mymessage})  //getting issue setState not found
         console.log(this.state)
      });
      });
};
this.sock.onmessage =(e) =>{
console.log('message', e);
alert("on message calledj")
};
this.sock.onmessage = evt => {
console.log("erve");
}

}
```

In this code I am  able to get net message inside new_message variable but not able to update state value here .
Any solution of this condition .

Comment: You should show us where this onOpen function is declared and and how you are setting the state. Primary guess is that since `onOpen` is not bound to any this, it usually holds the `this` of where ever it was invoked from which would not be the component instance itself resulting in `setState` not being found.

Comment: Hi @Panther , I have updated my code . Have a look .

Comment: stompClient.subscribe function call after getting message from socket connection ,

Comment: Cool. Any reason you are using `function` instead of `arrowFunction` while you have used arrow function for others. Try to use arrow function(that will bind the function to the class) or you manually bind the function to the class instance and it should work for you

Comment: yes thanks. I fixed it by using arrow function .That was my fault . I was following some document.